# Can one install Automator .workflow services via Terminal without user consent?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automator, services

I know I can just use `open` command on these files to run them and the user will be prompted with an option to install them. Can I install such services silently though?

Comment: You can use cp, mv, or ditto to move or copy the file.

Comment: @IronCraftMan and copy it to the default automator library? Hm. Does that operation do the same as service 'installation'?

Comment: I don't know, and I can't test it at the moment, but you can. I'd assume there is no difference.

Comment: @IronCraftMan This is elegant and simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved the Automator services to `$HOME/Library/Services/` instead of installing them.